# Exactly Position on String Search Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I need to get exactly hits for what I search it.
Lets say we have 3 documents with single field (user.created_at) and content like this:

```
Wed Mar 04 09:14:25 +0000 2020
Wed Mar 25 12:14:25 +0000 2020
Wed Mar 25 06:14:25 +0000 2020
```

Then my query in RAW is

```
 {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "user.created_at.keyword": "*2020"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "user.created_at": "Wed Mar 25"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "user.created_at": "Wed Mar"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "user.created_at": "Mar 25"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "user.created_at": "Wed"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "user.created_at": "Mar"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "user.created_at": "25"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to search only for **Wed Mar 25**, it can happen, that I get the result keep showing hit that contain **Wed Mar 04 09:14:25 +0000 2020** :

```
Wed Mar 25 12:14:25 +0000 2020
Wed Mar 25 06:14:25 +0000 2020
Wed Mar 04 09:14:25 +0000 2020
```

Anyway, the field type is **String**, I don't have any idea to update mapping type to date. An error like

```
{
 error: {
  root_cause: [
   {
    type: "resource_already_exists_exception",
    reason: "index [final/KyzdFVn4RnCicyphDFBW-w] already exists",
    index_uuid: "KyzdFVn4RnCicyphDFBW-w",
    index: "final"
   }
  ],
  type: "resource_already_exists_exception",
  reason: "index [final/KyzdFVn4RnCicyphDFBW-w] already exists",
  index_uuid: "KyzdFVn4RnCicyphDFBW-w",
  index: "final"
 },
 status: 400
}
```

I'm totally out of idea. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a [match_phrase query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) with a slop of 0. This specific query will ensure all terms are found in order.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "user.created_at.keyword": "*2020"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "user.created_at": {
              "slop": 0,
              "query": "Wed Mar 25"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It will not handle all cases but when searching for "Wed Mar 25" you will only get

```
Wed Mar 25 12:14:25 +0000 2020
Wed Mar 25 06:14:25 +0000 2020
```